Finite state automaton
Recently, I have been trying to understand Kitaev's textbook Classical and Quantum Computation, in which he defines a (finite-state) automaton as a function $D:Q\times A'\to Q\times A''$ where $Q$ is a finite state space and $A',A''$ are the input, output alphabets (say all $\{0,1\}$ for simplicity), i.e., $D(q,x)=(q',y)$. One can then apply this sequentially as shown in the following diagrams so that the input is $q_0,x_0,\cdots, x_{m-1}$ and the output is $q_{m},y_0,\cdots, y_{m-1}$.
There is then an Exercise (2.11) which states that this can be computed by a circuit of depth $O(\log n)$. Question: Why?

Specifics. Luckily, the text already provides a solution. However, I'm have trouble understanding it. More specifically, using the example of $m=2^{\ell}$ with $\ell=3$, the solution draws the following diagram to obtain $q_i$ for each $i$ in parallel. If I understand correctly, to get from say $q_0 \to q_{2^{\ell}}$, we require a circuit of depth $O(\ell)$, since (roughly) $q_{2^{\ell}}$ is obtained from $q_0$ by the composition of $2^{\ell}$ functions and thus using a binary tree, it takes $O(\ell)$ depth to compute. If so, then to obtain say $q_{1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^{\ell-1}}$ (e.g., $q_7$), I am required to compute $q_{2^{\ell-1}}$ first from $q_0$ (which requires $O(\ell-1)$) and then $q_{2^{\ell-2} +2^{\ell-1}}$ from the output $q_{2^{\ell-1}}$ (which requires another $O(\ell-2)$). Continuing this process, it would take $O(\ell^2)$ depth to compute all $q_i$'s, so I'm a bit confused how this can be optimized to have only depth $O(\ell)$?

